# Formatting Chapter Title/Header (Report Class)

Tags: formatting, header-footer, chapters

I am writing a dissertation using the `report` class. At present, each chapter page looks like the image below.

[image]

Note the large space between the beginning of the page and "Chapter 1". A MWE is given by

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Biological background}

\end{document}
```

Ideally I would like to mimic the style shown in the below image.

[image]

Is this possible? This is my first time posting, and I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this befit you? I used `titlesec` to redefine the formatting of chapters. In `\titlespacing` `*6` means a vertical spacing (after the title, as it is the last argument) of `6ex`, with a minute schrinkability/strechability if necessary.

Unrelated: loading `inputenc`is no more necessary, as utf8 has been thedefault expected encoding for more than three years.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=3cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\Huge}{\chaptername~\thechapter.}{0.5em}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{*0}{*6}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Biological background}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful! How can the size of the chapter title be adjusted? Do we have to alter  the command `\Huge`?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that. The first argument of the command sets parameters (font size, font shape, &c.) that apply to the whole title head (label and title). The second argument applies to the label, the third is the separation between label and title) and the fourth argument is for commands that apply to the title. I use `\Huge` because it is the default for the title in the report class. Note that for the label , the default is a bit smaller (\huge).