# How do I move my chapter titles closer to the edge of the paper?

Tags: spacing, chapters

I want to move my chapter title closer to the edge of the paper so I can fit more words on one page. I have attached my preamble and how my page looks right now[image: Preamble].[image: How my page looks currently]

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\Huge}{\chaptername~\thechapter.}{0.4em}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{*0}{*1}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} 
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\captionsetup[figure]{margin=1.5cm,font=small,labelfont={bf},name={Figure},labelsep=colon}
\captionsetup[table]{margin=1.5cm,font=small,labelfont={bf},name={Table},labelsep=colon}
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599185 answer your question?

Comment: This kind of worked, I adjusted the margins to make them wider which helped reduce some of the whitespace. Definitely looks better to me so thanks for the help @PeterWilson.

Comment: It would be better to post code instead of a picture of code if you expect help. That way people interested in helping you don't have to type all of this themselves. Also, it is often advisable and preferred to try to keep the code posted as minimal as possible, yet complete to show your issue.